# Renaming Multiple Columns in R using Rename

Tags: r, rename

I have already checked the forum for the solution but could not find the solution, hence, posting the problem here.
I am trying to change a name of a column using `Rename`, although the command is executed without any error but the names of the columns does not change.
I use this code`rename(red,parts = category)` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a named vector as the second argument, and the names need to be quoted. Also, don't forget that you need to overwrite `red` with the result.

```
red <- reshape::rename(red, c(parts = "category"))
```

If you want to change multiple columns, add the items to the named vector you supply to the second argument.

Comment: The query you provide does not change the name of the column.

Comment: @TaimurKhan this should work. If you are having problems, perhaps you could edit your question to show what `red` is: if you type `dput(head(red, 10))` and paste the output into your answer, I'm sure I can fix this for you. Have you checked that `parts` doesn't have a capital letter?

Comment: Now working fine. Can you please tell me in a bit more detail about changing multiple columns

Comment: @TaimurKhan suppose I have a data frame called `df` with columns called "x" and "y" but I want to change these to "apples" and "oranges". Then I would do `df <- reshape::rename(df, c(x = "apples", y = "oranges"))`.

Comment: The query you provide is also working without the "reshape" function.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem.